# Filter a js array of object based on 2 conditions

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. I want to keep the objects with ID: 0 but remove the duplicates from the array where id > 0.

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 0, name: 'a'},
  {id: 0, name: 'b'},
  {id: 0, name: 'c'},
  {id: 2, name: 'd'},
  {id: 3, name: 'e'},
  {id: 3, name: 'e'},
];

console.log(
  arr.filter((v, i, a) => a.findIndex(t => (v.id === 0 || t.id === v.id)) === i)
);
```

I expect the following output

```
0: {id: 0, name: 'a'}
1: {id: 0, name: 'b'}
2: {id: 0, name: 'c'}
3: {id: 2, name: 'd'}
4: {id: 3, name: 'f'}
```

How can I achieve that? I guess I am just missing a logic in my current code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close, I would take the `0` condition out of the `findIndex`

```
let arr2 = arr.filter((a, i) => {
    return a.id === 0
        || arr.findIndex(aa => aa.id === a.id) === i
})
```

Comment: Just curious, Why to use `findIndex` and increase time complexity to O(n*2), when we can use dictionary...

Comment: @decpk - no reason - I'm not concerned with performance with an array length of 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to achieve the desired result.

It is the **efficient** solution because it takes only one iteration of `arr` to get the desired result and takes constant time to `add` and `has` to add and check if the `id` exist.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 0, name: "a" },
  { id: 0, name: "b" },
  { id: 0, name: "c" },
  { id: 2, name: "d" },
  { id: 3, name: "e" },
  { id: 3, name: "e" },
];

const dict = new Set();
const result = arr.filter(({ id }) => {
  if (id === 0) return true;
  else if (!dict.has(id)) {
    dict.add(id);
    return true;
  } else return false;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is simple, but there are some performance drawbacks.
If you're only filtering through a few objects, it shouldn't take too long.

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 0, name: 'a'},
  {id: 0, name: 'b'},
  {id: 0, name: 'c'},
  {id: 2, name: 'd'},
  {id: 3, name: 'e'},
  {id: 3, name: 'e'},
];

let newArray = [];
let arrayOfIds = [];

arr.forEach(obj => {
  if (obj.id === 0) {
    newArray.push(obj);
    arrayOfIds.push(obj.id)
  } else if (!arrayOfIds.includes(obj.id)) {
    newArray.push(obj);
    arrayOfIds.push(obj.id);        
  }
})

console.log(newArray)
```